# Trying to get VBA to click a button on a web page

Tags: vba, excel

Im looking for assistance completing this code for clicking a 'GO' button on a web page.

Here is the code from the website

```
<span class="button-g">
   <a href="class=" autoCompleteGoButton" Style="margin:0 0 0 10px;"onclick="javascript:cfMainFormSubmit();">go</a>
</span>
```

Here is the code that I have been trying work with.

```
'click the 'go' button
Set objInputs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each ele In objInputs
If ele.Class Like "autoCompleteGoButton" Then
    ele.Click
End If
Next
```

Here is the code that I'm using maybe this will help.

```
'start a new subroutine called SearchBot
Sub SearchBot()

    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
    Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
    Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
    objIE.navigate "https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml"

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'in the search box put cell "A2" value, the word "in" and cell "C1" value
    objIE.document.getElementById("cfsearchtextboxmain").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value & ", " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value

    'click the 'go' button
     IE.document.getElementById("communityfactssubmit").Click

    'wait again for the browser
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Comment: Is scraping allowed for this site? Also, there is an API https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/acs-5year.html

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Trying to click the go button, I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
IE.document.getElementById("communityfactssubmit").Click
```

As there appears to be an id you can use:

[image: HTML]

This is using the [link](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/community_facts.xhtml) you provided, which unlike the HTML you show, does have an Id for this button.

If the element is not immediately found make sure you are waiting until page has loaded with:

```
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Before attempting the click.

You can add additional wait time with

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,2) '<==replace 2 with number of seconds to wait
```

---

**Edit:**

I just tested the following full script successfully:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend '<== Loop until loaded

         .document.querySelector("#cfmainsearchform > a").Click

         STOP '<== Delete me later
        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Better option: Use the free API**

I would also highly recommend first using the Fact Finder to explore data of interest and note specific variables/datatables of interest and then moving to using the API to handle these requests. It will be faster and cleaner.

There are a series of tutorials on how to use this API [here](https://github.com/uscensusbureau/Census_Academy/tree/master/Courses/01_API_Introduction).

Dataset info [here](https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/acs-5year.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I tried what you recommended and it still did not work. I do have the wait time in my code. I keep getting a run error 424.

Comment: No I cannot. When I go onto the website the HTML is different. I also added the code above maybe that will help.

Comment: The HTML also changed for me. And then later, access was denied.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just ran your code and it worked perfectly! @QHarr

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you need to do here.

Is to traverse into the HTML Element itself.

You have two options depending in the structure of the site.

But based on the given Screen shot. I will assume that this is the hierarchy or the structure of the site.

One thing that you need to do here is to go the inner class of the span tag which is "button-g" then to the AutoCompleteGoButton class.

```
Dim spanElement as Object, buttonElement as Object

Set spanElement = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button-g")
Set buttonElement = spanElement(0).getElementsByClassName("AutoCompleteGoButton")

buttonElement(0).Click
```

Please take note that (0) is the index number of that element. Assuming that these elements are the only HTML Elements having these class names on the webpage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have linked the website Im trying to use. I hope this can help you out. I tried running the code and it did not work. It looks like the span repeats a few times through out the code I counted 4 times so I put a 3 instead of the 0 and ran that with no luck. https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/community_facts.xhtml

Comment: Your provided html do not match with the one connected to the `GO` button in that webpage @Slayerxx128.

Comment: You must know what is the index of that specific span. 

To help you what index is that span. You can try to use Debug.print spanElement(indexNumber).innerText. 

Now it can help you out if you are targeting that specific class.

Comment: Ill try this out. I understand what your saying. Just trying to figure out how to add it into the code. I'm a noob at this stuff so its a learning curve for me. @BLitE.exe